# Malformed records are detected in schema inference parsing json

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a really frustrating error trying to parse basic Json read from Blob Storage using a data set within ADF

My Json is below

```
[{"Bid":0.197514880839,"BaseCurrency":"AED"}
,{"Bid":0.535403560434,"BaseCurrency":"AUD"}
,{"Bid":0.351998712241,"BaseCurrency":"BBD"}
,{"Bid":0.573128306234,"BaseCurrency":"CAD"}
,{"Bid":0.787556605631,"BaseCurrency":"CHF"}
,{"Bid":0.0009212964,"BaseCurrency":"CLP"}
,{"Bid":0.115389497248,"BaseCurrency":"DKK"}
]
```

I have tried all 3 Json source settings and every one of them gives the error

```
Malformed records are detected in schema inference. Parse Mode: FAILFAST
```

The 3 settings as in

```
Single Document
Array Of Documents
Document Per Line
```

Can anyone help?  I just simply need this to be a list of objects thats it!

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work for the JSON setting - `Array of documents`.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you tweak this reply to show Encoding as US-ASCII please?  That was the fix (although its actually more of a workaround) I think its still useful to keep this question because its a really subtle issue and you have listed the steps clearly here - I am getting the JSON from an API

Answer (score 2):

We face this issue when we have the json file with UTF-8 BOM encoding, the ADF DataFlow is unable to parse such files. You can specify the encoding as UTF-8 without encoding while creating the file, it will work.

In my case, I am using copy activity to merge and create the json file and have specified encoding as UTF-8 without BOM, and it resolved my issue.

Note: For some reason, we cant use the dataset which has "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding in DataFlow, in that case, you can create two datasets one with default UTF-8 encoding (which will be used in DataFlow) and one with UTF-8 without BOM(which will be used in copy activity sink/while creating a file).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What if Structure is like this-

```
{
    "GroupId": 1,
    "SubGroups": [
        {
            "GroupId": 101,
            "SubGroups": [
                {
                    "GroupId": 10101,
                    "SubGroups": [],
                    "Type": "AA",
                    "Name": "Name1"
                }
            ],
            "Type": "A",
            "Name": "Name2"
        },
        {
            "GroupId": 102,
            "SubGroups": [],
            "Type": "B",
            "Name": "Name3"
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a brief explanation please?